# Как выбрать дочерние элементы другого родителя?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть такая структура HTML. Ее менять нельзя. 
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на блок, менялся цвет только выбранного блока, его текст и текст под блоком. И **border** при наведении тоже меняется.

При нажатии на текст под блоком, текст и блок тоже меняются
И при нажатии на блок повторно, он восстанавливался в первоначальное состояние.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".block").click(function() {
    this.bool = true;
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
    $(this).find(".text").css("color", "red");
    $(this).parents().find(".under-box-text").css("display", "none");
    $(this).parents().find(".invisible").css("display", "block");
  });

  $(".link").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
    $(this).parents().find(".invisible").css("display", "block");
    $(this).parents().find(".block").css("border", "1px solid red");
  });

  $(".block").mouseenter(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("boolean")) {
      $(this).css("border", "4px solid #e62e7a");
    }
  });

  $(".block").mouseleave(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("boolean")) {
      $(this).css("border", "4px solid red");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.block {
  background: #444;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div>
      <p class="text">
        some text for block 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="under-box-text">
      Under box <a class="link">click here</a>
    </p>
    <p class="invisible">
      Done!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div>
      <p class="text">
        some text for block 2
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="under-box-text">
      Under box <a class="link">click here</a>
    </p>
    <p class="invisible">
      Done!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так? вроде ничего не пропустил)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".block").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
  });

  $(".link").click(function() {
    var wrapper = this.closest('.wrapper');
    $(wrapper).find('.block').toggleClass('active')
  });
  
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: #444;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.active.block:hover {
  border: 4px solid #e62e7a;
}

.active .text {
  color: red;
}

.active.block:hover .text {
  color: #e62e7a;
}

.active + div .under-box-text {
  display: none;
}

.active + div .invisible {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div>
      <p class="text">
        some text for block 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="under-box-text">
      Under box <a class="link">click here</a>
    </p>
    <p class="invisible">
      Done!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div>
      <p class="text">
        some text for block 2
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="under-box-text">
      Under box <a class="link">click here</a>
    </p>
    <p class="invisible">
      Done!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: при наведении на активный блок, цвет текста внутри тоже должен меняться на, как и рамка

Comment: @Imp3l поправил

Comment: совсем забыл. Если есть третий блок, который по структуре такой же. Но он как бы не активный (другим цветом), как можно сделать, чтобы он не реагировал на нажатия по нему и не менял свой цвет.

Comment: @Imp3l каким образом не активность задаётся?

Comment: все что внутри блока opacity: 0.5

Comment: @Imp3l это opacity классом добавляется каким-то или как?без кода третьего блока не понятно.

Comment: Все разобрался, просто блоку в стилях прописал pointer-events: none;